# how tow avoid this below scenario get the unique value

Tags: sql, oracle

how tow avoid this below scenario get the unique value

```
INPUT
id  bike  car   bus  htv
ss   Y    N      N    Y
ss   N    N      N    Y
KK   Y    N      N    Y
KK   N    N      N    Y

OUTPUT (expected)
id  bike  car   bus  htv
ss   Y    N      N    Y
KK   Y    N      N    Y
```

can you share the query for helpful?

Comment: What is the logic to how you pick the values you want in the output?

Comment: A simple statement of the conditions that lead to Y or N in a particular case would mean a potential answer is not a guess. In IT the ability to ask/frame a question is often more important that just knowing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just aggregate and take the max of each column:

```
SELECT
    id, MAX(bike) AS bike, MAX(car) AS car, MAX(bus) AS bus, MAD(htv) AS htv
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
```

The reason this should work is that `Y` (for yes) is lexicographically larger than `N` (for no).  So if, for a given `id`, there be even one yes value, the above query would report yes.  It would only report no in  the case that a given column has no everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here are several ways depending on how you want to pick the retained values:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46f81/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, bike, car, bus, htv ) AS
SELECT 'ss', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ss', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'KK', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'KK', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**: Get the maximum value for each column for each id group:

```
SELECT id,
       MAX( bike ) AS bike,
       MAX( car  ) AS car,
       MAX( bus  ) AS bus,
       MAX( htv  ) AS htv
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46f81/4/0)**:

```
| ID | BIKE | CAR | BUS | HTV |
|----|------|-----|-----|-----|
| ss |    Y |   N |   N |   Y |
| KK |    Y |   N |   N |   Y |
```

**Query 2**: Get the first row found in each id group:

```
SELECT id, bike, car, bus, htv
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46f81/4/1)**:

```
| ID | BIKE | CAR | BUS | HTV |
|----|------|-----|-----|-----|
| KK |    Y |   N |   N |   Y |
| ss |    Y |   N |   N |   Y |
```

**Query 3**: Get the row with the highest `bike`, then highest `car`, then highest `bus` then highest `htv` for each `id`:

```
SELECT id, bike, car, bus, htv
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY id
           ORDER BY bike DESC, car DESC, bus DESC, htv DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46f81/4/2)**:

```
| ID | BIKE | CAR | BUS | HTV |
|----|------|-----|-----|-----|
| KK |    Y |   N |   N |   Y |
| ss |    Y |   N |   N |   Y |
```

**Query 4**: Get the row with the highest number of `Y` columns for each `id` group:

```
SELECT id, bike, car, bus, htv
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY id
           ORDER BY
               DECODE( bike, 'Y', 1, 0 )
             + DECODE( car,  'Y', 1, 0 )
             + DECODE( bus,  'Y', 1, 0 )
             + DECODE( htv,  'Y', 1, 0 ) DESC,
             ROWNUM
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46f81/4/3)**:

```
| ID | BIKE | CAR | BUS | HTV |
|----|------|-----|-----|-----|
| KK |    Y |   N |   N |   Y |
| ss |    Y |   N |   N |   Y |
```